# How to update and save a record just after the record has been save for the first time?

Tags: acumatica

I've got the OpportunityID field which is a numbering sequence, and when it's saved for the first time I want the UsrEBDR Field to be updated with the opportunityID value.

So on INSERTING into the database, I want to copy the OpportunityID field to the UsrEBDR Field.

The OpportunityID field is an Autonumbering Sequence so in the RowPersistingEvent it has not yet been calculated by the framework.

so I tried overriding the RowPersisted event but I get an exception on MoveNext and it doesnt save my record.

Do you have an idea?

```
protected virtual void CROpportunity_RowPersisted(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e, PXRowPersisted del)
        {
            if (del != null) del(sender, e);
            CROpportunity row = e.Row as CROpportunity;
            if(row == null) return;
            if(e.Operation == PXDBOperation.Insert && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.GetExtension<CROpportunityExt>().UsrEBDR) && e.TranStatus == PXTranStatus.Open)
            {
                Base.Opportunity.Current.GetExtension<CROpportunityExt>().UsrEBDR = row.OpportunityID;
                Base.Persist();
            }
        }
```

Edit:
Thus far I got it working by doing this :

```
 protected virtual void CROpportunity_RowPersisted(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e, PXRowPersisted del)
        {
            if (del != null) del(sender, e);
            CROpportunity row = e.Row as CROpportunity;
            if(row == null) return;
            if(e.Operation == PXDBOperation.Insert && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.GetExtension<CROpportunityExt>().UsrEBDR) && e.TranStatus == PXTranStatus.Completed)
            {
                row.GetExtension<CROpportunityExt>().UsrEBDR = row.OpportunityID;
                using(PXTransactionScope ts = new PXTransactionScope())
                {
                    var restrictOpportunityId = new PXDataFieldRestrict<CROpportunity.opportunityID>(row.OpportunityID);
                    var assignEBDR = new PXDataFieldAssign<CROpportunityExt.usrEBDR>(row.OpportunityID);
                    PXDatabase.Update<CROpportunity>(assignEBDR, restrictOpportunityId);
                    ts.Complete();
                }
            }
        }
```

Yet I feel it's an improper use of the framework, and it's not really "clean", if someone has any idea how to make it clean.

Answer (score 1):

Put your logic in `RowPersisting` and let the system save by itself. Calling Persist from Persist leads to many problems that are easily avoided if you simply modify the record before its persisted.

```
void CROpportunity_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e, PXRowPersisting del)
{
   // Don't call save action or persist
   // Just modify data and let the system save
}
```

Comment: My problem is when I debug with a breakpoint in the RowPersisting method, the OpportunityID is not set yet (it's still '<NEW>'), so i can't default the UsrEBDR to the value of the opportunityID.

Comment: Database generated fields get their value after they are persisted. What you're trying to achieve seems to be copying ID field in custom field. This can probably be done with formula. You could override Persist method but I'd still recommend you avoid the Persist in Persist anti-pattern at all costs.

Comment: The proper pattern is to use attributes to set field values or create a custom DAC and have PXParent refer to ID of child.

Comment: Maybe the easiest way would be to determine what's the next number to be generated by the Autonumbering sequence and put it in the rowpersisting event ? 
I'm a bit frutrated on this because using persist in the rowpersisted was working fine in 6.10, and in the 2018R1 release it breaks my customization.

Comment: Both are anti-patterns to be reliable the keys have to be managed automatically by the system. Manually setting keys also causes issues. I think you need to  design your solution to adhere to these constraints. The other option that comes to mind would be to bypass the framework by saving with PXDatabase object which isn't recommended either.

Comment: I'm failing to see how I could do this with a PXFormula, or a PXParentField referencing a field from the same DAC. Since it's just a version upgrade changing the whole design of the customization is not an option.

Comment: It ain't gonna work if you don't change anything. You can move the logic from RowPersisted handler to Persist method override. However it tends to have the same issues when you Persist from there too.  If that's the case substitutiting Persist with a call to PXDatabase.Update could work because PXDatabase doesn't trigger the same events that Persist would.

Comment: I went for the PXDatabase.Update, but i'm not happy with this solution, there should be a way to generate the next value for an autonumbering sequence without actually burning this value.

Comment: To my knowledge there isn't. Database generated fields have to round trip to the database first. During persisting, the record didn't hit the DB yet and there could be no reliable way to guess the next ID due to database concurrency issues.

Comment: By design you can't reserve ID. If process A were to reserve ID 1 and not use it immediately, which ID would process B use? ID 2? Wait for process A to finish? That could lead to deadlocks. What if process A never completes, what happens of the unused ID 1? Is there a time-out on unused reserved ID? Would the next record be ID 3 or 1? Both are wrong because we want to keep AutoNumber ID in perfect sequential order without any gaps in numbering. The way to ensure that is to lock database when generating ID and prevent reserving ID. Doing otherwise could be very complex.