# How do I capture the PO references assigned into SOLineSplit3 during POCreate for an SO?

Tags: acumatica

I have a modification that facilitates an internal business process utilizing PO and SO.  The screen provides the ability to purchase an MRO spare part outside of the normal replenishment process.  The item may or may not be maintained in inventory, so it may be ordered for replenishment or as an SO to be processed as Mark for PO.

In creating the SO, I am able to store the SO reference information to the DAC for my customization.  When creating the PO directly, I also am able to capture the PO reference information.  However, when creating the PO from the SO using the standard Acumatica menu action for Create Purchase Order, I have been unable to capture the right event to enable storing the PO reference being assigned in SOLineSplit3 to my custom DAC.  (Worth noting that I also need to be able to override the default curyunitcost value on the PO line using the value stored on my custom DAC as these purchases do not carry a fixed price per buy.  This is done by tracing the SOLineSplit back to my custom DAC and overriding POLine_CuryUnitCost_FieldDefaulting.)

The action invoked on the Sales Order Entry screen (Action - Create Purchase Order) calls the method CreatePOOrders in POCreate.cs which in turn creates an instance of the POOrderEntry graph to create the actual purchase order.

Eventually, the following code is reached, which appears to attach the PO reference information to SOLineSplit3 as soline:

```
soline.POType = line.OrderType;
soline.PONbr = line.OrderNbr;
soline.POLineNbr = line.LineNbr;
soline.RefNoteID = docgraph.Document.Current.NoteID;

docgraph.UpdateSOLine(soline, docgraph.Document.Current.VendorID, true);

docgraph.FixedDemand.Cache.SetStatus(soline, PXEntryStatus.Updated);
```

I am not yet familiar with Cache.SetStatus, but the pop-up description seems to indicate that this is using the FixedDemand select in POOrderEntry to find and set (or insert) the SOLineSplit3 record.  The call to UpdateSOLine above it is a new internal method that was not in my previous version of POCrete.cs, as this entire method seems to have had some significant rework recently.  In trying to capture events on SOLineSplit3 in both POCreate and POOrderEntry, it appears that Cache.SetStatus does not raise any events that I can capture... or I am just completely lost on what event to capture/override.

Immediately following this section, the following appears to update a Replenishment record and save the entire POOrderEntry graph.

```
if (docgraph.Transactions.Cache.IsInsertedUpdatedDeleted)
{
    using (PXTransactionScope scope = new PXTransactionScope())
    {
        docgraph.Save.Press();

        if (demand.PlanType == INPlanConstants.Plan90)
        {
            docgraph.Replenihment.Current = docgraph.Replenihment.Search<INReplenishmentOrder.noteID>(demand.RefNoteID);
            if (docgraph.Replenihment.Current != null)
            {
                INReplenishmentLine rLine =
                    PXCache<INReplenishmentLine>.CreateCopy(docgraph.ReplenishmentLines.Insert(new INReplenishmentLine()));

                rLine.InventoryID = line.InventoryID;
                ...
                rLine.PlanID = demand.PlanID;
                docgraph.ReplenishmentLines.Update(rLine);
                docgraph.Caches[typeof(INItemPlan)].Delete(demand);
                docgraph.Save.Press();
            }
        }
        scope.Complete();
    }
...
}
```

Basically, I need to insert my code right between the assignment of the PO information to "soline" and the docgraph.Save.Press(); without copying dozens of lines of code to modify this method.  I have managed cloning the base method and inserting my code successfully, but I'd prefer to use an event handler and eliminate modifying the standard code.  But the question...  What event in which graph will let me grab the PO information and follow the breadcumbs back through SOLineSplit to my custom DAC?

Acumatica Build 18.212.0033

Comment: Can you identify which specific event you need to override? 
DAC + Event Type, for example POLine_RowInserted?
That is the hard part to understand for me, I don't know which event to target from your business rules. Besides that, the solution is to intercept the POOrderEntry graph (with InstanceCreated) created by action Create Purchase Order and hook events on the intercepted graph.

Comment: I have been trying to override SOLineSplit3_RowUpdated as I need to grab the SO information from the SOLineSplit and attach the PO references to my custom DAC.  I have also tried other variations on field level events and even trying to hit RowPersisting and RowPersisted, but the DAC I need accessible to my update is SOLineSplit3.

Comment: Working on an example, my computer is very slow but I should have something soon.

Answer (score 0):

Extend `POCreate` graph because it is the one instanciating the `POOrderEntry` you are interested in.

Setup a hook on any `POOrderEntry` graph created by `POCreate` and subscribe your events on the intercepted graph. I tested this solution, with a Sales Order that has allocations lines in allocation window it will catch the `SOLineSplit3` events:

```
public class POCreate_Extension : PXGraphExtension<POCreate>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<POOrderEntry>((graph) =>
        {
            graph.RowInserting.AddHandler<POOrder>((sender, e) =>
            {
                PXTrace.WriteInformation("POOrderEntry_POOrder_RowInserting");
            });

            graph.RowInserting.AddHandler<POOrderEntry.SOLineSplit3>((sender, e) =>
            {
                PXTrace.WriteInformation("POOrderEntry_SOLineSplit3_RowInserting");
            });

            graph.RowUpdating.AddHandler<POOrderEntry.SOLineSplit3>((sender, e) =>
            {
                PXTrace.WriteInformation("POOrderEntry_SOLineSplit3_RowUpdating");
            });

            graph.RowPersisting.AddHandler<POOrderEntry.SOLineSplit3>((sender, e) =>
            {
                PXTrace.WriteInformation("POOrderEntry_SOLineSplit3_RowPersisting");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a new set of tricks to me, but the only one that picked up was POOrderEntry_SOLineSplit3_RowPersisting which did not show the PO number at the time.  Before your suggestion, I was trying to capture events directly in POOrderEntry since that is the graph that is being called.  What I need to do is to inject my code in the code sample above at the same point that docgraph.UpdateSOLine is called, as that is the point where I know the PO line and SOLineSplit at the same time to be able to attach the PO to my DAC.  The only way I have been able to make this work is to clone the entire method

Comment: There's nothing in Acumatica to inject code in the middle of the method. If events aren't called it's a safe bet to assume it's because they're never triggered in the first place. SOLineSplit3 is a projection and is used outside Sales Order, I wouldn't expect POCreate to modify them unless there's evidence to the contrary.

Comment: To get your code in the middle of the method you need to redefine it. In this case the proper way would be to override POCreateFilter_RowSelected and after base event call you set your own process delegate to be called instead using Base.FixedDemand.SetProcessDelegate(…) method.

Comment: Thanks.  I need to read up more on projections as I've not had to work with them yet.  I also am not sure what "docgraph.FixedDemand.Cache.SetStatus(soline, PXEntryStatus.Updated);" does, as it seems like it could be what is acutally saving the values but not triggering events in the process.

Comment: To trigger value from code, method SetValueExt needs to be used for assignation. Other types of assignation won't trigger updated events. SetStatus just set a dirty flag, it's often a sign that workarounds are involved. I also suggest avoiding projection if possible as it raises many unanswered questions about whether or not it will react like standard DACs in many situation.

Comment: One step closer using your earlier suggestion. I tried POOrderEntry_SOLineSplit3_RowPersisted and have all the PO info at that point, along with the SOLineSplit.  But I'm not supposed to persist inside a rowpersisted to save to my other DAC.

Comment: If you need access to a DB generated field then you must hook after Persist actually occurred in DB since the value is null before that. One way or another you'll have to Persist from a Persist event. That typically creates infinite loop but you can get away with it by persisting using the PXDatabase.Update method which doesn't raise the events leading to infinite persist loop. I've touched on that in the comments of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53541910/7376238